# how to install bootstrap using local files

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I just realized that my site has not been using the local files of bootstrap and was getting theme via CDN.  I've now been trying to figure out how to switch from CDN to using the local files, but every time I attempt to switch them my whole site becomes messed up. I have the bootstrap css files in a css folder as well as the js files in a js folder. Can anyone help me get bootstrap from my local files?

This probably seems like an easy question however I'm still pretty new at this, so I'm completely lost.

what I had before in my functions.php...

```
function learningWordPress_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');
```

what I tried to switch it too...

```
function learningWordPress_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapthemestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), true );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');
```

[image]

Comment: the first example loads the default stylesheet style.css but the second does not.    Im a little confused because the first example, which you say works, has a css file as the script in the wp_enqueue_script line.

Comment: I really don't know if the second code is coded correctly. I'm just trying to place things somewhere. The problem is for the past few weeks I have thought I've been getting bootstrap off of my bootstrap local files.  However, Ive just been getting them from the CDN.  So a few days ago when I tried to customize bootstrap it didn't work. I then figured out it's because it was not loading the local bootstrap files at all but the generic CDN code. If that makes more sense.

Comment: Could you add a link to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to load three files:    css, javascript, and your local style.css file:

Here is what I do on my [Legal Firm Website](https://trulaw.com) - you can view the source yourself.

```
   function btc_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.5' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'btc-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' , array ('bootstrap-style'),'1.0.1');

        wp_enqueue_script ( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', false);

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'btc_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!